# Twilio Javascript Voice SDK - Non US users can only call in incognito browser

Tags: twilio, twilio-javascript

Very strange problem.   All of my users that are not in the US, when making inbound or outbound calls, the codec in conference insights is undefined and thus both the caller and the callee only hear silence.  Domestic users have no issues.

However if I have the same overseas users attempt in an incognito browser, it works!

We have forced conference regions to us1, we've forced device edge locations to ashburn.

I've attached the results from networktest.twilio.com for one of the effected users, the success screenshot is in an incognito broswer and the failed is a regular chrome browser, same machine, same ip, same location, same time.

what could be different between regular and incognito that would determine success or failure?

[image: incognito success]

[image: Traditional failure]

Additionally the console logs from both cases, incognito an ICE Candidate is located, in a regular browser it is null.

[image: console log of regular browser failure]

[image: console log of incognito browser success]

Comment: Are there any browser extensions that might be causing this that aren't run in incognito mode?

Comment: You are the man Phil!  Embarrassed I didn't think of that!  Turns out all of the overseas employees had a particular VPN chrome extension installed.   THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

I would check for any browser extensions that may be causing this in regular mode but are not running in incognito mode.